# Python: How to get, process, convert image url with ".thumb" extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-requests, python-imaging-library

What can I use to read, process, convert, save, etc. image url with ".thumb" extension?

I rarely seen an image url with ".thumb" extension, so not sure which tool to use with it.

I tried using Requests to get the image from the URL and save as ".thumb" image format. But when I open the image, it is blank.

```
import requests
import shutil

image_url = 'https://slickdeals.net/attachment/5/4/8/0/7/1/200x200/9242327.thumb'
resp = requests.get(image_url, stream = True)
local_file = open('local_image.thumb', 'wb')
resp.raw.decode_content = True
shutil.copyfileobj(resp.raw, local_file)
del resp
```

Its the same if I save it as .jpg or .png. The image is blank.

Comment: A thumb file is a thumb.db file. You seem to need to need sqllite3 to get the data out of the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You couldn't convert it directly because the bytes of the image is `*.thumb` not `*.jpg` or `*.png`.

And there is no need to use `stream=True` in your code.the image is not very large.
This code could download it directly:

```
import requests

image_url = 'https://slickdeals.net/attachment/5/4/8/0/7/1/200x200/9242327.thumb'
resp = requests.get(image_url)
with open('local_image.thumb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

And you also could use `PIL` to convert it to `jpg`,like:

```
import requests, io
from PIL import Image

image_url = 'https://slickdeals.net/attachment/5/4/8/0/7/1/200x200/9242327.thumb'
resp = requests.get(image_url)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(resp.content))
image.save("local_image.jpg")
```